# checkbox = true still won't show checkboxes in fancytree

Tags: javascript, fancytree

I have this fancy tree

`$('#my_id').fancytree({
               checkbox: true,
               selectMode: 3,
               source :myDataSource,
               extensions: ['filter'],
               quicksearch: true, 
            });`

`myDataSource =  [
                   {
                    title: "Everything",
                    id:"11",
                    folder:true,
                    children:[
                        {
                          title: "Node 1", 
                          id: "1"
                        },
                        {
                          title: "Folder 2", 
                          id: "2", 
                          folder: true, 
                          children: [
                                      {
                                        title: "Node 2.1", 
                                        id: "3", 
                                        myOwnAttr: "abc"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        title: "Node 2.2", 
                                        id: "4"
                                      }
                                    ]
                            }
                         ]
                     }
                 ]`

But the fancytree is not showing checkboxes to its nodes. What am I missing?
Also when I try to access the selected nodes using `$('#my_id').fancytree('getTree').getSelectedNodes();`
, it throws an error.

Comment: What does the `extensions: ['filter'],` do?   If I remove that line, then the code appears to work.  http://jsfiddle.net/fLn68orx/74/

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual code and concrete error message . Maybe you can set up a jsFiddle, CodePen, or Plunkr

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8f0pxcqn/23/) is a jsFiddle I tried to create. Please pardon me if any mistake as I am not very familiar with jsFiddle.   @mar10

Comment: I could fix the error. It was some silly mistake. But the check box issue still remains.

Comment: I observed one thing. If include the ui.fancytree.min.css and jquery.fancytree-all-deps.min.js using the hyperlink themselves, it works fine. But if I download those files and include them locally, it won't work.

Comment: Solved! As it turns out, I had not added the .gif files. Took me time to understand the working of fancytree.